# Cannot get React Router working with Webpack and historyApiFallback when server under '/path'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, traefik

I am struggling to get my app set up properly.

It is React app with React router, running inside docker behind Traefik proxy.

The app is served under: `myapp.localhost/boilerplate`. I had issues to make it work under this path but changing `output.publicPath` and `devServer.publicPath` to `/boilerplate` made it work so main page is loading correctly.

However, I cannot get React Router working in this setup. In Webpack config I have enabled :`devServer.historyApiFallback`, however it does not work. The webpack output is already a bit alerting:

```
app-boilerplate  webpack output is served from /boilerplate 
app-boilerplate Content not from webpack is served from /srv/www/boilerplate/src 
app-boilerplate 404s will fallback to /index.html
```

I think it should already know that 404 will fallback to /boilerplate/index.html and that is why I keep getting 404 on any subroute.

What should be done? I suppose in the dev environment it has to be done in Webpack conf (but probably could also be done in Traefik?) and for production, it can be then handled by the reverse proxy.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: You have to configure your server to serve `index.html` for every route, like you said. The webpack dev server is not active in production, so `historyApiFallback` has no effect. You also have to configure the [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) of React Router if your site's root is `/boilerplate`.

Comment: I have stated that it is dev environment so it is running webpack dev server inside the docker container so it is up to Webpack dev server at the moment and t this moment I am not yet at ReactRouter config as it doesn't throw React error, but pure 404 from dev server